# How to sample from the prior predictive distribution in jags?

Tags: bayesian, prior, jags

Is there an example available of how I can sample from the prior predictive distribution (without data) in jags? I would like to get a better sense for the contribution of the prior in a multilevel model using jags.

I could probably set up a simulation manually using R, but since I already have the distributional relationships set up in jags, it would be preferable if I could do it without setting up duplicate simulation code in R.

Comment: I think you can do this just by passing "NA" instead of the actual values for the target variable to JAGS, and of course asking JAGS to return the target variable.  Your sample would be multivariate, with one component for each observation, but there would be no estimation going on because JAGS has no target variable data.